# how many possibilities translation of ばかな/ばかね？

Tags: expressions

I know ばか literally means "stupid/idiot" but i remember a scene when i was re-watching naruto.  the context is:

"sarutobi asuma just got news that his close skilled friend (old comrade of him) was killed by akatsuki, he was very shocked and could not believe such a very strong, skilled friend was killed easily by akatsuki and then he said 'ばかな! bla bla bla'." i am sorry i can't fully provide what he said because my limited japanese skill.

I dont know equivalent of that word in english in the context above, maybe " huh, how can?". correct me if i am wrong.

so when is 'ばかな' used other than to insult people? and is it okay to say it to close friend (older) as expression?

Comment: In that context, at least, I think he was probably saying "Foolish!" or something... I would need more of the Japanese context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Impossible!"

"I can't believe it!"

"No way!"

These can be expressed with "ばかな！".

Comment: thats all? and is it okay to say it to older people?

Comment: Okay, in that case, you may think the translation is "Sh**!" You should not use it in a formal setting.

Comment: btw i just tried to translate "impossible" to japanese. it says "不可能". is it interchangeable with ばかな or was meant for another purpose?

Comment: 不可能 is mostly used in a formal sentence. For example, "It is impossible for North Korea to use a nuclear weapon actually." 北朝鮮が実際に核兵器を使うのは不可能だ。ばかな is used in a colloquial situation, so they are usually not interchangeable.

Comment: can it be used as expression as well? and if ばかな is used not for formal setting, then what is polite version of saying "no way" ?

Comment: 「それはないと思います。」「それはないでしょう。」「それはあり得ないと思います。」「それは不可能でしょう。」「うそでしょう？」

Comment: @Kakashi, be weary of one word translations. Sometimes, when multiple translations are given, the word you are trying to understand is often a mix of the two.